# Playing videos in a C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, wmplib

I have a C# desktop application that needs to play video files.

I am currently using the WMPlib, along with Interop.WMPLib and AxInterop.WMPLib.

Using this I can play WMV videos, but I need to be able to play more formats, such as MKV, MP4, AVI, OGV and MOV.

Digging through MSDN I found a comment that said that it only supported the "default codecs", but didn't specify which ones they were... I can't seem to find a list of the supported codecs for this lib online either..

How can I implement multiple format playing? Am I even able to do it? The documentation for this isn't exactly very clear and my googling only got me this far..

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is a media player that can play just about any unencrypted audio/video file. You can use its functionality as a library in .NET, e.g. with [libvlcSharp](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp).